# Android - Playing and stopping sound

Tags: android

What is the best way to play a sound and stop it?

I tried using RingtoneManager, MediaPlayer and SoundPool, but failed to stop the sound.

Is there a way to stop sound when using RingtoneManager TYPE_ALARM?

Please a simple snippet.

This is the last thing I tried:

```
        SoundPool pool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    List<Integer> streams = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int soundId = pool.load(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.alarm, 1); //There are several versions of this, pick which fits your sound


    try{

        if(myWifiInfo.getRssi() < -55)
        {
            /*
            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
            r.play();*/

            Thread.sleep(1000);
            int streamId = -1;
            streamId = pool.play(soundId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
            streams.add(streamId);
            textRssi.setText(String.valueOf(myWifiInfo.getRssi() + " WARNING"));
        }
        else {
            Log.e("WIFI","Usao");
              for (Integer stream : streams) {
                  pool.stop(stream);
              }
              streams.clear();
            Log.e("WIFI","Izasao");
        }
```

Comment: Post the code that you've tried.  I know I've seen the stop method work for mediaplayers and sound pools.

Comment: @GabeSechan edited the post. Here you go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this function gets called many times?  The problem is that you're adding the streamID to a local list.  That list is getting recreated each time the function is called, so when you try to call stop the list will always be empty.

If its only being called once, then the problem is you're never calling stop, only play (they're in separate branches of that if).

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but it doesn't work. The sound also stops playing after certain amount of time, but not when it should.